# Why can't I use break inside my python loop?

Tags: loops, python-3.x

I am a new programmer that just learned python so I made a small program just for fun:

```
year = int(input("Year Of Birth: "), 10)

if year < 2016:
    print("You passed! You may continue!")

else:
    break
```

I searched this up and I tried using break but I got a error saying I have to use break outside of the loop. Can anyone give a simple solution? Thanks.

Comment: There's no loop in the code that you posted.

Comment: When I was younger, I once ordered Coca Cola without whipped cream. It completely confused the waiter, despite the fact that serving Coca Cola *with* whipped cream never even crossed his mind. You using `break` outside a loop is similar to that.

Comment: "I got a error saying I have to use break outside of the loop" - no, you got an error saying that you *are* using break outside of a loop, and you *shouldn't* do that. It's not saying you have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`Break` is used in a `loop`. For example:

```
i = 3

while True:
    i = i + 1 #increments i by 1
    print(i)
    if i == 5:
        break

print("Done!")
```

Normally, `while True` will execute indefinitely because `True` is always equal to `True`. (This is equivalent to something like `1==1`). The `break` statement tells Python to stop executing the loop right then and there. Then, it will continue executing code where the while loop left off.

*The output of this program will be:*

```
4
5
Done!
```

First, `i=3`. Then, in the `while` loop, `i` becomes `4`, and `4` is outputted to the console. Since `i` is not equal to `5`, it does not `break`.

Now, `i=4`. `i` increments to `5` and is printed to the console. This time, `i==5`, so it `break`s. Then, it prints `Done!` because that line is after the `while` loop we just broke out of.

Answer (score 0):

`Break` is used inside a loop to get out of that loop which looks something like `while`, `for` and you are trying to use it in Flow Control statements i.e `if` , `elif` and `else`